# Saving dynamically created button android

Tags: java, android, button, save, dynamically-generated

I am trying to save a button that I make dynamically on a separate activity, but I cant seem to get it to work.  Here is what I have tried in my CreateButton.java:

```
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

public static int generateViewId() {
    for (;;) {
        final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
        // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
        int newValue = result + 1;
        if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
        if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

public void Submit (View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CreateNewClass.this, MainActivity.class);
        EditText mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        String name = mEdit.getText().toString();

        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_semester);
        String semester = mEdit.getText().toString();

        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_year);
        String year = mEdit.getText().toString();

        Button myButton = new Button(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            myButton.setId(generateViewId());
        }
        else {
            myButton.setId(Button.generateViewId());
        }

        myButton.setText(name + " " + semester + " " + year);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, layoutParams);

        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

And here is my .xml for the activity_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button_so"
        android:text="@string/Google"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:onClick="goToGoogle"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/newClass"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_su"
        android:onClick="goToCreate"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It creates the button dynamically on the mainActivity and navigates to it, but I cannot get it to save the button, it immediately goes back to just the two original buttons.

Any help is really appreciated, I am a newbie and am just trying to learn some of this stuff on the side.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're first setting the View using `setContentView`, which basically just displays the Layout you have inflated inside your current Activity.
And after that you're starting a new Activity, which launches a completely independent View on its own and therefore does still display the default buttons.

If you want to set the text and add the Button inside the actual Activity, it is a good practice to pass the String as an Intent Extra.

So your `submit` method should look like this:

```
//by the way you shouldn't start method names with upper case
public void submit (View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CreateNewClass.this, MainActivity.class);
        EditText mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_name);
        String name = mEdit.getText().toString();

        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_semester);
        String semester = mEdit.getText().toString();

        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.class_year);
        String year = mEdit.getText().toString();

        String buttonText = name + " " + semester + " " + year;

        myIntent.putExtra("button_text", buttonText);

        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

And in your `MainActivity` you can then place the button by pasting the following code into the `onCreate` method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String buttonText = intent.getStringExtra("button_text");

//activity could also be started without providing the extra
if(buttonText != null){
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(buttonText);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
      (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(button, layoutParams);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, since you're trying to achieve something a bit different, than I thought, you should try an other approach.

You are trying to get a `Result` from the second Activity and therefore it would be perfect to use the `startActivityForResult()` (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)) method here.
I assume that your application is using the `MainActivity` as the first Activity that gets shown.

Instead of launching the second Activity by issuing `startActivity()` you use `startActivityForResult()` providing any constant as request code.
In your `submit` method you can then remove the `startActivity(myIntent)` line and instead place the following code there:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntent);
finish();
```

In your MainActivity again you can now override the `onActivityResult` method with the following implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //you specified the request code before, when launching the second activity
    if(requestCode == ADD_USER_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String buttonText = data.getStringExtra("button_text");
            if(buttonText != null){
                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setText(buttonText);
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                ll.addView(button, layoutParams);

                //here comes the part that saves the button strings persistently
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                Set<String> buttonSet = prefs.getStringSet("saved_buttons",null);
                if(buttonSet == null){
                    buttonSet = new HashSet<String>();
                }
                buttonSet.add(buttonText);
                prefs.edit.putStringSet("saved_buttons", buttonSet).commit();
            }

        }
    }
```

And finally you need to rebuild the old layout when the activity gets relaunched. Place the following code inside the `MainActivity.onCreate`, delete the Intent Extra stuff.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Set<String> buttonSet = prefs.getStringSet("saved_buttons", null);
if(buttonSet != null){
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_screen);
    for(String buttonText : buttonSet){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(buttonText);    
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
          (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(button, layoutParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton, this works, but I want to be able to any amount of buttons rather than just a single.  This seems to just add a button to the original screen and if I attempt to add another, it just changes the text of that button rather than adding a fourth button

Comment: Actually it does not overwrite the previous button, but the old ones aren't saved anywhere. Do you need them to be saved, so they are accessible after an application relaunch? Or do you only need them as long as the Activity is displayed?
And are all the Strings for all Buttons you want to add available at the same time?

Comment: Ah, yeah I kind of got that just worded it incorrectly.  I'm definitely trying to be able to save the buttons so that they are accessible after a relaunch.  I only have the string available for one button at a time.  So in theory I would start with one button on the main screen, the add button.  I would press the add button on the main screen, fill out the name on the second screen, and then have 2 buttons, the add and the newly created.  Then pressing add and doing it again would yield a 3rd...  If there is an easier way of doing this than I'm thinking feel free to tell me, I'm very new to it

Comment: I think I know what you try to do now.. Checkout my edit

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for.  startActivityForResult works perfectly for it, and I'm pretty sure I understand it enough to implement it myself in the future.  Thank you a ton, the answers were really helpful and descriptive!

Comment: I'm really happy you find it useful!
Have a nice day